# creating plist in speficied format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, plist

I want to create plist in below format.

[image]

What I have is three NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *friends; --> Item 0 >> Objects
NSMutableArray *followers; --> Item 1 >> Objects
NSMutableArray *following; --> Item 2 >> Objects
```

I am able to get three arrays as specified but not getting how I will write all three data in format as shown in above image.

**Note:**

Item 1 and Item 2 will have same format of objects as Item 0.

---

What I want to do is save the data in plist as show in above image format (with the data that  I have in NSMutableArray)

In this file I would be saving the userlist data and after some duration I will be checking whether new data is added or not and if added, I will revise the file.

**With FORMAT, I meant, the way data is arranged and not how the data is encoded (xml, binary)**

Comment: What do you mean by "format"? Do you want to choose between the legacy, the XML and binary formats and serialize the property list object?

Comment: I think you mean structure (how the data is arranged), not format (how the data is encoded, eg binary, xml)

Comment: yes, how the data is arranged...

Comment: @H2CO3 : With format, I meant, the way data is arranged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user in each collection is a `NSDictionary` with the following structure:

```
NSDictionary *user1 = @{ @"name": @"Rashid", @"profileId": @"1", @"level": @(1) };
```

And each collection is an `NSDictionary` with the following structure:

```
NSDictionary *plist_friends = @{ @"name": @"FRIENDS", @"profileId": @"0", @"level": @(0), @"Objects: @[ user1, ... ] };
```

Finally, the plist represents an array of collections:

```
NSArray *collections = @[ plist_friends, plist_followers, plist_following ];
```

which are housed in a dictionary with a single key, Objects:

```
NSDictionary *plist = @{ @"Objects": collections };
```

Comment: I have edited your answer... Now how can I add friend (I have this as NSMutableArray) in plist_friends

Comment: `@"Objects: friendsArray`

Comment: it working but have one problem.. If you see, after root, it starts as objects... When I do something with your code, it shows Root >> Item 0... any idea how to do this??

Comment: `NSDictionary *plist = @{ @"Objects": collections };`